# Problema para carregar imagem em hospedagem especifica

Tags: php, html, hospedagem

Alguém utiliza o serviço de hospedagem da empresa *000webhost* para fazer testes ? Eu estou enfrentando um problema com imagens que não estão carregando, a 'pasta' esta lá e a 'imagem' está lá com os nomes corretos mas mesmo assim não carrega

Realmente eu não faço ideia do que pode ser.

Código do arquivo *index.php*

```
<div class="logo">
    <figure>
        <img src="logo/logo.png" alt="Logo da empresa Hard">
        <figcaption>
            Logo da empresa Hard
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Esta é a resposta html do servidor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aba network

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifica no `Console` se esta retornando algum erro.

Comment: nenhum erro no console

Comment: E na aba *Network* ? Esta qual o *status* que está retornando ?

Comment: atualizei o post

Comment: Já tentou colocar o caminho completo? Com o endereço do site? Está usando `.htaccess` ?

Comment: sim ja tentei usando `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/logo/logo.png"` e o mesmo erro acontece

Comment: será que tem algo haver com a extensão .php do index? por que eu fiz um site com extensão .html e carregou as imagens corretamente.

Comment: Jah testou em outros navegadores?

Comment: sim testei no Mozilla e no Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Com certeza deve ser problema no caminho do link, ou a imagem não existe no servidor (tente acessá-la direto pelo `link` da imagem no navegador).

---

**Uma solução e dica pro seu projeto:**

Acredito que tenha um arquivo de `config/settings` que é adicionado em todas as páginas, para fazer conexões com o banco ou definir variáveis usadas no projeto. Defina o link completo neste arquivo e chame em qualquer parte do código. Exemplo:

```
define('_BASE_URL_', 'http://www.exemplo.com.br/');
define('_BASE_URL_SSL_', 'https://www.exemplo.com.br/');
define('_JS_DIR_', _BASE_URL_.'js/');
define('_CSS_DIR_', _BASE_URL_.'css/');
define('_IMG_DIR_', _BASE_URL_.'images/');
```

Assim poderá ter um controle melhor do seu projeto, simplesmente printando a variável com o nome do arquivo que quer carregar na página.

```
<img src="<?php echo _IMG_DIR_."logo.png"; ?>">
```

Comment: sim eu ja fiz desta forma tambem porem nao tive exito mas obrigado pela dica

Comment: eu dei continuidade no projeto e tirei do ar, quando estiver mais completo vou por no GitHub dai eu te mando.

Comment: e ae cara beleza? então como os sabichoes ali em cima nao conseguiram responder decidiram fechar a pagina mas eis aqui a solução basta colocar o `<img>` dentro de uma `<section>` e resolvido projeto pronto segue link do site http://hardmaquinas.com.br/

Answer (score -1):

Ja tentou usar o base na sua index?

Nao esqueca o primeiro slash "/"

```
<base href="/Diretorio completo da sua img">
```